# Android Studio | Button animation when clicking

Tags: android, animation, button

First of all sorry for any bad english. (its not my native language)

Im looking for an animation for a button that will go down when clicked.

this is my first view.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingStart="30dp"
    android:paddingTop="170dp"
    android:paddingEnd="30dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/login"
        android:onClick="login" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="register"
        android:text="@string/register"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" />
```

and when I click on of the buttons, the other one will fade away (i know how)
and the view will transform into the second view (below the first view).

the second view:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingStart="30dp"
    android:paddingTop="170dp"
    android:paddingEnd="30dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/text_input_email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        app:errorEnabled="true">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:hint="@+string/email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/text_input_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        app:errorEnabled="true"
        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">


        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:hint="@+string/password"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/login"
        android:onClick="login" />
```

I can draw it also if im not clear enough.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

you can use this :

create animation resources file with name (click_anim.xml) into anim directory in res:

click_anim.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

 <alpha
    android:fromAlpha = "1.0"
    android:toAlpha = "0.5"
    android:duration = "100">
 </alpha>
 <scale
    android:fromXScale = "1"
    android:toXScale = "0.9"
    android:fromYScale = "1"
    android:toYScale = "0.9"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:duration = "50">
 </scale>
</set>
```

now you can use this animation for all `button` , `Textview` or... in your `activity`.

for buttons you must put it in OnClickListener.

```
login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            login .startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.click_anim));
        }
    });
```